# Invisible to internet on alternating boots?

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, internet

*(sorry for the length -- trying to answer as many questions as I can at the beginning)*

My small office has four Ubuntu 18.04.4 Server systems connected to the internet (with static IP addresses) through a device provided by Spectrum Internet. Three machines were upgraded from 14.04->16.04->18.04 and work extremely reliably. When COVID-19 hit, I set up a new machine, using a brand new, just out of the package hard drive with the current Ubuntu 18.04.4 installer to act as an OpenVPN server for our office network while we work from home.

That's all done and working great, except for one nagging problem: Any time I need to reboot our working vpn machine, I can no longer see it from the internet beyond the Spectrum-provided interface. I can ping the internet address from any of our other computers and all of those Ethernet cables go directly from the computers to the Spectrum device, so the pings are going through the device 'locally' but somehow no incoming traffic at all seems to reach the VPN box. The VPN box can, however, see the internet and receive data it has requested. It appears that only unsolicited traffic, such as ping or incoming VPN connections, cannot get through.

I can fix it by using SSH to connect to one of the other machines, then again from there to the VPN machine and booting it ONE more time. Then it works perfectly.

While I expect everyone here to blame Spectrum, there **MUST** be something different about my clean Ubuntu install because it is the only one that behaves this way. While testing this issue, I re-installed from scratch (re-partitioning and reformatting the drive each time) and discovered that this happens with only the base Ubuntu installed. **ZERO** additional packages are 'required' to get this strange alternating behaviour -- I just install, assign the internal and external IP addresses and run. One boot, pings from the internet are answered, on the next, they are not even received (according to `tcpdump`), repeat this cycle every boot.

I would really like to correct this behaviour so that the system is truly reliable in case it reboots on its own for any reason (like flickery Florida power) and I'm not around to help manually correct it. Unfortunately, I do not have a clue what could cause something like this. Any ideas?

[EDIT3: I was wrong]

This appeared to be fixed for the several boots I performed while testing the EDIT2 change but the issue is back and the system is once again only visible to the internet on alternating boots.  It still responds just fine to pings and other expected traffic on the internet NIC (and IPv4 address) when accessed by other computers connected to the same switch (a cable modem with 5 ports, all connected to IPv4 addresses in my assigned internet address block.)  This never happens to the other four machines running the exact same version of Ubuntu.  I really wish I had an idea of what to pursue.

[EDIT2:  Followup]

I (finally) removed the second .yaml file shown below and now the system comes up and works perfectly on every boot.

So, only one question remains:

Why did the system work differently on odd/even boots with my mistaken configuration?  I don't expect the system to pick and choose configurations at boot time, I expect the same config every time.

Perhaps this should be resubmitted as a new question, but I'm not sure how to title it.  Would anyone care to suggest something?

[EDIT1:  Adding requested command output]

NOTE: I obscured our external addresses because I don't want to set myself up as a target, but I'm certain they are correct.

NOTE 2: I have no idea why there are two network sections in the netplan file. Could that cause the system to alternate which one it chooses each boot or something?

NOTE 3: These are long after all my struggling to get a bridged OpenVPN working, but the problem existed with the fresh, clean install as well.  **BEFORE** I attempted to change any of these files or settings.

```
steve@vpn:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8139 Ethernet
       vendor: D-Link System Inc
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:05:04.0
       logical name: enp5s4
       version: 10
       serial: 00:0d:88:2d:d4:9b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=aa.bb.cc.dd latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:c800(size=256) memory:fbbfeb00-fbbfebff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NC100 Network Everywhere Fast Ethernet 10/100
       vendor: ADMtek
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:05:05.0
       logical name: enp5s5
       version: 11
       serial: 00:20:78:0f:d1:ed
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=tulip driverversion=1.1.15 latency=64 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:17 ioport:cc00(size=256) memory:fbbfec00-fbbfefff memory:fbc00000-fbc1ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: br0
       serial: c6:94:aa:54:63:49
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.42.2 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: tap0
       serial: 2e:ac:be:7a:43:f6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair promiscuous=yes speed=10Mbit/s
steve@vpn:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).

network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp5s4:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses:
            - aa.bb.cc.dd/29
            gateway4: aa.bb.cc.ee
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - xx.yy.zz.1
                - xx.yy.zz.2
        enp5s5:
            dhcp4: no
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [enp5s5]
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.42.2/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.42.2
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.42.4,192.168.42.1]
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).

network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp5s4:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses:
            - aa.bb.cc.dd/29
            gateway4: aa.bb.cc.ee
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - xx.yy.zz.1
                - xx.yy.zz.2
        enp5s5:
            dhcp4: no
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [enp5s5]
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.42.2/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.42.2
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.42.2,192.168.42.4,192.168.42.1]
            parameters:
                hello-time: 2
                max-age: 12
                stp: on
                priority: 1000
                forward-delay: 9
steve@vpn:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Comment: Did you open ports in the firewall? Do you have to forward ports through the Spectrum device?

Comment: We have no control over the Spectrum device, but we were told that our assigned IP addresses would be fully visible on the internet. While testing, with a 'virgin' system I had whatever the installer set up. Nothing extra or changed.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.